# Show that every fraction whose square root is rational takes the form $kp^2/kq^2$.

Tags: proof-verification

Show that every fraction whose square root is rational takes the form   $kp^2/kq^2$.

**What i've done:**

We're given that $$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{p}{q}$$
Take $p/q$ as a fraction in  lowest terms,then by squaring we get (assuming that $a,b$  $>0$):
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$$
Since $p^2/q^2$ is also a fraction in lowest terms( since if we had $p^2/ q^2 =xs/xt$ we would have a contradiction about $p/q$ being in lowest terms),we have that every other fraction,say $c/d$, which is equal to  $\sqrt{a/b}$ must be of the form $kp^2/kq^2$ .

**Question:** Is this valid as a proof,if not where does it fail ?If you can provide also other proofs about the proof in question i'd appreciate.

P.S: i apologize if my latex syntax isn't really appropriate.

Comment: The proof is somewhat valid. You have to motivate why $p^2/q^2$ is in the lowest terms too (which shouldn't be too hard given unique prime factorization). BTW using (la)tex is appropriate (at least if it works).

Comment: You should use different letters for different variables. Otherwise it's fine.

Comment: Is it fine now ?

Comment: If for a number theory course, it would likely be assessed as incomplete. Note that it includes a proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. In some contexts the argument should be viewed as being adequate.

Comment: the proof is only for myself.Could you tell me why it would  be incomplete for a number theory course ?